# Help with modelling a piezo

Tags: modeling, transient, piezo, oscillation, piezoelectricity

I'm using the Van Dyke model from [this](http://www.vtvt.ece.vt.edu/research/papers/08sas.pdf) article and I'm a bit lost on a few things.

1. Since the only nodes I can physically connect to are the ends, can I assume that I am limited to the voltage across the parallel capacitor?
2. I have derived the following equation for this network:
   $$
   \frac{d^2i}{dt} + \frac{R}{L}\frac{di}{dt}+\frac{1}{LC_1}i_1 = \frac{1}{LC_o}i_o
   $$
   Going back to #1, I guess I'd only need to solve for the right half of this to get the transient response.  But this is simply a tank circuit now, which negates the rest of the piezo circuit.

what is the proper way to model this in a circuit?  I want to model a piezo to see it's response to a pulse.

thanks.

**EDIT:**

A little more context on the problem I'm having.  here is what I want to model:
[image]

The switch closes momentarily and opens.  A measurement on an oscilloscope shows this:[image]

The main resonance is the larger one - the other ones are assumed to be reflections within the medium.  Ultimately, I would like to create a model for this behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure about your equation.  Won't R_1 and L_1 only see current i_1?  And some other equation i=i_0+i_1.

Comment: What do you mean by response to a pulse? Please define input (pulse source) and output. Possibilities are electrical voltage and current, mechanical displacement, mechanical velocity, mechanical force, acoustic pressure,...

Comment: Get a piezo data sheet and look at the model. I've seen a few data sheets that have models.